# My colors are getting messed up when I give them an alpha value

Tags: android, colors

I have a ListView, and I want the items to show a different color than Holo Blue when they're pressed. So I made a selector drawable and it works great.

My color is `FFF100`, a nice yellow.

However, I think it's a bit too saturated, so I want to bring down the alpha to make it more like my tab indicator, which is done with an image file. It has the same color, `FFF100`, but with 50% opacity.

So I changed my color to an ARGB value, using `80` (128/255) as the alpha value. So my color is now `80FFF100`.

But now it looks like a weird green![image: Screenshot]

And my colors.xml:

```
<resources>
    <color name="putio_accent">#FFF200</color> **This is the standard yellow color. Using this works fine, but it's too saturated, like I said before.
    <color name="putio_accent_selected">#80FFF100</color> **This should be the same, but with 50% alpha..
</resources>
```

Why is this happening?!

Comment: Can you show the code or XML you're using to set the color?

Comment: Made a discovery! When adding an alpha value, it's _also_ drawing the Holo Blue, and combining it with my yellow. That's why it's all green. Blue + Yellow = Green, duh! So why is it showing the blue?

Comment: How are you adding the background color? It's probably still using the old background resource + yours...

Comment: I'm putting `android:background="@drawable/putio_clickable_bg"` in the XML for my individual ListView Item layout. Is that wrong?

Comment: Depends on what your `putio_clickable_bg` `drawable` is. But... it SHOULD overwrite the default background...

Comment: Here's my putio_clickable_bg: http://pastebin.com/hGLyJbFv

Comment: That's the list's layout, not the `drawable`.

Comment: ..why did I do that? But anyway, I found the problem, the selector wasn't it. I'm making an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it's doing that exactly without seeing code, but you could always just convert your ARGB color to RGB, using this:  foreground * alpha + background * (1-alpha)

Or take a snapshot and yank the color directly (which would change the color you want to f7f077).  Of course if your background is not solid, then you can't do this, but from your picture that doesn't appear to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. The reason it was showing up green was because for some reason, Android was showing the default pressed color (Holo blue) and *combining* it with mine. Blue + yellow = green!

I fixed it by taking out this line in my row's XML:

```
android:background="@drawable/putio_clickable_bg"
```

and putting this line into my ListView:

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/putio_tab_indicator"
```

Why this fixes it, I don't know. Maybe it's a bug in Android?

Comment: I'd guess the `ListView` probably has its selector behind the background of the selected item. So, you see its background + the selected item's background. I'd think this would be by design. Glad you found a solution!

Comment: Seems logical. It'd also explain why when I took the `background` line out of the row's XML, and made the `listSelector = #00000000`, nothing showed up at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of what really happens when you use other numbers like '80' in the alpha columns. I have only used '00', try that as this gives a perfect colour with about 50% opacity. It appears that not using 0s changes the colour.

Hope this helps.